# how to create a circle's bounding box android

Tags: android, bitmap, geometry, bounding-box

I have a bitmap that sets two variables centreX, centreY through the onTouchEvent() method. From these x,y co-ordinates i draw a circle over the bitmap and can change the circle's pixels to different rgb values through a slideBar. I target the circle's inner pixels with an algorithm but unfortunately as it stands i have to search the entire bitmap pixel by pixel to target the circle's pixels. this has a massive method call overhead that i'd like to reduce.

What i'm thinking of doing is creating a bounding box around the circle so my algorithm has less space to search, so will speed things up hopefully. How can i create a rectangle arounf the circle using the circle's x,y centre co-ords and a radius of 50?

Thanks matt.

```
public void findCirclePixels(){ 


        for (int i=0; i < bgr.getWidth(); ++i) {
            for (int y=0; y < bgr.getHeight(); ++y) {

    if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centreX, 2) + ( Math.pow(y - centreY, 2) ) ) <= radius ){

                    bgr.setPixel(i,y,Color.rgb(Progress+50,Progress,Progress+100));
                }
            }
        }   

        }// end of changePixel()
```

Comment: I suppose, it would be much much cheaper to draw a new circle. You should consider introducing a framestep or just clear and recreate the screen contents

Comment: @kostja hi there, i'm not sure if you understand my requirements, sorry if you do:). i'm only setting the circle's pixels to a differnt colour to make sure that the slidebar and pixels algorithm are tageting the correct pixels. the app will eventually apply a fisheye effect on the circle.(basically distort the circle's pixels). The only way i can find the circle's pixels in the bitmap is search the whole bitmap left to right, top down, pixel by pixel. i'd like to only search a rect around the circle and so have less calls.

Comment: I thought I understood your requirements, but I'm not so sure anymore, especially about the why :) Please disregard my first comment if it does not fit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your outer loop limits from circle.x - radius to circle.x + radius, and your inner loop limits from circle.y - radius to circle.y + radius.  You may, depending on what your x and y can be, need to check if any of those values are less than 0 or greater than the limits of your images width or height.

Comment: clay hi, isn't my outer loop limit bgr.getWidth()?

Comment: clay i'm not sure if you meant the following answer but this is what i did, and it is much faster now, thanks.

Comment: @turtleboy, I'm glad that it's faster for you, but if I understand what you did you should be able to make it faster still by changing the limits to what I said.  You should be able to do something like "i=circle.x - radius; i <= circle.x + radius; ++i) {" and "y=circle.y - radius; y<=circle.y + radius; ++y) {".  Again, you would have to check that when you subtract the radius it isn't less than 0, and that when you add the radius to circle.x that it isn't bigger than bgr.getWidth(), and that when you add the radius to circle.y that the result isn't bigger than bgr.getHeight().

Comment: clay ok i'll give it a go your way, but if the radius is 50 then the diameter is 100, so im looping an imaginary box that is 100x100. the edges of the circle will be touching this imaginary box so i can't think it will get much faster. thanks for the advice and ill let you know if it indeed speeds things up:). next on list is asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine.

```
 public void findCirclePixels(){    



        for (int i=centreX-50; i < centreX+50; ++i) {
            for (int y=centreY-50; y <centreY+50 ; ++y) {

    if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centreX, 2) + ( Math.pow(y - centreY, 2) ) ) <= radius ){

                    bgr.setPixel(i,y,Color.rgb(Progress+50,Progress,Progress+100));
                }
            }
        }

        }// end of changePixel()
```